# remove n occurrences of exclamation marks in a string javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am wondering if anyone knows how to replace `n` number of occurrences of exclamation marks in a string. I need to remove `n` exclamation marks in the sentence from left to right and `n` is always positive integer.

An example would be as follows:

```
remove("Hi!!!",1) === "Hi!!"
remove("!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi",3) === "Hi !!hi!!! !hi"
```

I have tried many approaches but have had no luck so far. Here is my latest attempt.

```
function remove(str, n){
   str.replace(/!{n}/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters) function in `.replace()` to replace only the first number of items upto the passed value of `num`:

```js
const remove = function(str, n) {
  let i = 0;
  const res = str.replace(/!/g, match => i++ < n ? '' : match); // if i is smaller than the num, replace it with nothing (ie remove it) else, when i becomes greater, leave the current matched item in the string and don't remove it
  return res;
}

console.log(remove("Hi!!!", 1)); // === "Hi!!"
console.log(remove("!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi", 3)) // === "Hi !!hi!!! !hi"
```

Or, if you like, a one-liner:

```js
const remove = (str, n) => str.replace(/!/g, match => n --> 0 ? '' : match); 

// Results: 
console.log(remove("Hi!!!", 1)); // === "Hi!!"
console.log(remove("!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi", 3)) // === "Hi !!hi!!! !hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Match/replace all exclamation marks, but check `n` in the replacement function and conditionally return either an empty string (remove `!`) or the original string (keep `!`).

Also, decrement `n` each time a `!` is replaced by nothing.

```js
function remove(str, n) {
    return str.replace(/!/g, function (m0) {
        if (n > 0) {
            n--;
            return '';
        }
        return m0;
    });
}

console.log(remove("Hi!!!",1));
console.log(remove("!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi",3));
```

This algorithm removes all exclamation marks if `n` is higher than the number of `!` in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the count as counter and check ich it reaches zero. if not decrement and replace with an empty string, otherwise replace with the found string.

```js
const remove = (s, n) => s.replace(/\!/g, _ => n && n-- ? '' : _);

console.log(remove("Hi!!!", 1) === "Hi!!");
console.log(remove("!!!Hi !!hi!!! !hi", 3) === "Hi !!hi!!! !hi");
```